# How to properly save instance of FileField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Im hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction.

So, I am creating an array of Model objects and then doing a `bulk_create` at the end to save them to the database. The one thing I am having an issue with is after I added the the `FileField` I cannot exactly how I need to associate data with that field. The files don't end up in the `upload_to` folder set nor do they end up being associated with the record itself. Id also add that I am using PyPDf2 to create the PDF files before trying to associate them to an instance of my model.

So to give you an idea on what I am trying to do. I am running this code to create the PDFs initially.

```
if pdf_file_name is not None:
            num_pages_current_doc = page['pageRange'][-1]
            input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_file_name, 'rb'))
            output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
            for _ in range(num_pages_current_doc):
                output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page_counter))
                page_counter += 1
            with open(str(uuid.uuid4())+'.pdf', 'wb') as output:
                output_pdf.write(output)
                logging.info(f'Wrote filename: { output.name }')
```

The saved file I then want to associated with a model instance below this, the code looks something like this:

```
document = document(
            location=location,
            Field2=Field2, etc etc .....
            pdf = ???
```

Im unsure how to set the field for that `pdf` part, Ive tried using the `File()` method on it. Tried putting just `output.name` for the field, Im not sure how to go about making this work.

Could anyone give me some insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the FieldFile.save(name, content, save=True) method in django docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile